# X86 Compiled Applications under Visual Studio 2013 won't run on some Windows 7 64-bit machines

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-7, x86

I have a Windows 7 SP1 16GB machine. I compiled an application targeted for the x86 environment. On my machine the application runs without any issues. However, on some other Windows 7 SP1 machines it gives the following error message.

The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows 
you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether 
you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then 
contact the software publisher.

I have installed the 2013 x86 and x64 redistributes, however that did not fix the problem.

.NET 4 is on the machine and that is my target for VS 2013 as well. I know I must be missing something obvious, but can't lock on to what might be missing.

I would compile the application for Any CPU, however when I do that, the DSN data that I'm reading from the SysWOW6432Node registry will give me a driver error if the application is not built under x86.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can offer.

```
CorFlags output on exe

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework CorFlags Conversion Tool.  Version  4.0.30319.33440
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 0x3
ILONLY    : 1
32BITREQ  : 1
32BITPREF : 0
Signed    : 0
```

One other bit of information is that in the event viewer the following error. I don't know if this will help, but thought I'd make it available.

```
- System
   - Provider
        [Name]           Wow65 Emulation Layer
   - EventID             1109
        [Qualifiers]     16384
     Level               4
     Task                0
     Keywords            0x80000000000000
```

Comment: The standard mistake is to pay too much attention to the Solution Platform name.  Its name is irrelevant for .NET projects, having "x86" selected does not mean that your program will run in 32-bit mode.  It matters for solutions that contain C++ projects.  For a .NET solution, only the EXE project's Platform target setting matters.  Project + Properties, Build tab.  Don't forget to also set it for the Release configuration.

Comment: Changing the release and the platform did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Hmm, you having to change it does explain why it didn't work originally.  Why it doesn't work now is harder to guess.  Run Corflags.exe for a second check on the .exe file.

Comment: see above for the CorFlags output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution to this issue comes from sending an EXE as a TXT file via email. Apparently, the email scanning process add something to the attachment that in turns makes Windows believe the EXE is not either x86 or x64. I was unaware of the user for whom I had given the EXE file to was sending it via email and then having the problem. I apologize for this omission and I thank everyone for their advice and information.